# Sequelize :: Limit and Order INSIDE an Include[] construct

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have the following model hierarchy:

```
User.hasMany(Child);
Child.hasMany(Profile);
```

Once I have a `User` object loaded, I need to load its `Children` and their associated `Profiles` according to the following logic:

1. Load all `Children` for the `User`, sorted by `name`.
2. For each `Child`, load the first three `Profiles` reverse sorted by `id`.

Is there a way to limit and sort the eager-loaded `Profiles`? I can limit and sort the `Children` but not the `Profiles`.

```
user.getChildren({
  limit: 10,
  order: [['name', 'ASC']],
  include: [{
    model: Profile,
    limit: 3,                <-- HAS NO EFFECT!!!
    order: [['id', 'DESC']]  <-- HAS NO EFFECT!!!
  }]
});
```

The only way I can make it work is by doing the following:

```
user.getChildren({
  limit: 10,
  order: [['name', 'ASC']]
}).then(function(children) {
  user.children = children;
  _.each(children, function(child) {
    child.getProfiles({
      limit: 3,
      order: [['id', 'DESC']]
    });
  });
});
```

This is both bad in my opinion and requires extra code to ensure I don't access the `Children` before all `Children` have been loaded.

Is there a way to specify `limit` and `order` options right inside the `include[]` construct?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about `limit`, but I tried with a simple `order` and it worked fine:

```
user.getPets({
    order: 'type ASC'
})
```

By extension, I would assume limit works too?

Comment: No, unfortunately it doesn't or I can't figure the right way to do it. Reporting the issue and asking the sequelize team https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/6891